# Reading XML in Asp.net not getting any results

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using following code to read an XML file from [this address](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml).

```
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");

        XmlNodeList nodeList = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//gesmes/Cube/Cube");

        if (nodeList == null) lblOutput.Text = "node is null";

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            XmlNode innerNode = node.SelectSingleNode(".//Cube");

            lblOutput.Text = innerNode.Attributes["currency"].Value;
        }
```

The problem is I don't get any thing. `nodeList.Count` always gives me `0`.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Comment: @ fhogberg: Yes. The one from you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the namespaces correctly.
There are probably more then one way to handle them and this is one

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
        XmlNamespaceManager xnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
        xnm.AddNamespace("gesmes", "http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01");
        xnm.AddNamespace("eurofxref", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");

        XmlNodeList nodeList = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//gesmes:Envelope/eurofxref:Cube/eurofxref:Cube", xnm);

        if (nodeList == null)
        { 
            var text = "node is null";
        }
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            XmlNode innerNode = node.SelectSingleNode(".//eurofxref:Cube", xnm);

            var text = innerNode.Attributes["currency"].Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it has to be this complicated but....

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();

xdoc.Load("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager xMan = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);

xMan.AddNamespace("def", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");

XmlNodeList nodeList = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//def:Cube", xMan);
```